# this.props.navigation.goBack() is not firing in createMaterialTopTabNavigator React Native React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, expo

I have a toptabnavigator (that I'm using to put tabs on the bottom of my screens) and I have a screen that is just not working when I call this.props.navigation.goBack(). Here is the code that I'm calling from the screen:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.closeLine} onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.goBack()}}>
      <Icon.Ionicons size={30} style={{ color: '#fff', fontWeight: 'bold' }} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? `ios-close` : 'md-close'} />
      <Text style={styles.closeText}>Close</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Here is the code for the tabnavigator:

```
// Bottom tab compilation
export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  DashboardStack,
  StatusStack,
  ReferralStack,
  MoreStack,
},
tabConfigs
);

const tabConfigs = {
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  tabBarOptions: {
    inactiveTintColor: '#364652',
    activeTintColor: '#ff6900',
    activeBackgroundColor: '#ff6900',
    indicatorStyle: {
      display: 'none',
    },
    showIcon: true,
    tabStyle: {
      width: '100%',
    },
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 11,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      marginBottom: 5
    },
    indicatorStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
    style: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95)',
      height: 55,
      width: '100%',
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      position: 'absolute',
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      marginBottom: isIphoneX() ? 30 : 0,
      shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 1,
      },
      shadowOpacity: 0.22,
      shadowRadius: 2.22,
    },
  }
};
```

The screen it's happening on is the MoreScreen, so here is the code for the MoreStack:

```
const MoreStack = createStackNavigator({
  More: MoreScreen,
  Monitor: MonitorScreen,
  Settings: SettingsScreen, 
  EditEmail: EditEmailScreen,
  EditPhoneNumber: EditPhoneScreen,
  EditPassword: EditPasswordScreen,
},{
  headerMode: shineHeaderMode,
  headerLayoutPreset: 'center',
  headerBackTitleVisible: false,
  headerTransparent: true,
  mode: 'modal',
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Menu",
      headerTransparent: true,
      headerTitleStyle: {
        color: '#425563',
      },
    headerStyle: shineHeaderStyle,
    }

});

MoreStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarVisible: false,
  tabBarLabel: 'More',
    tabBarIcon: ({focused }) => (
      <TabBarIcon source={focused ? require('../assets/icons/more.png') : require('../assets/icons/inactive-more.png')}/>
    ),
  mode: 'modal',
};
```

For some reason, when I call this.props.navigation.goBack() nothing happens at all.

**What I've tried:**
I've tried passing null, that just takes me to the first screen in the Dashboard Stack.

I've tried putting it in a different function altogether in the class (called like more_back()) and calling this.props.navigation.goBack() in that function and calling this.more_back() in the onPress method, and that didn't work either (meaning nothing happened onPress of the TouchableOpacity).

I've console logged out that it is actually catching the "pressed" event.

I've tried calling this.props.navigation.actions.goBack() to no difference in outcome.

**How can I make it so when I press that touchableopacity, it takes me back to the screen I was previously on?**

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your createMaterialTopTabNavigator in **createAppContainer** as per documentation in react-navigation v3.
You can checkout the official docs here [tab navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html).

```
export default createAppContainer(createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
...your routes...
}));
```

Comment: I'm not on version 3. Does that still apply?

Comment: No. It will not apply. You have to pass screen key as argument in **this.props.navigation.goBack(screen_key)**. you will get screen key from ```this.props.navigation.state.key```.Also add **initialRouteName** in your stack navigator.

Comment: So I changed all of my stacknavigators to have an initialRouteName (except the toptabnavigators) and I changed my call to this: this.props.navigation.goBack(this.props.navigation.state.key) and still no change